# How to make hover-active whole <li>, not just <a>?

Tags: css, hyperlink, cursor, html-lists

I have this HTML menu structure:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="cl1">item</span>
      <span class="cl2">price</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  ...
```

and CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  li {
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 5px 10px;
    a {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      span {
        display: block;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is, that if I move cursor into the `<li>` are, the link is still not active, I have to move cursor on the exact  link.

I would like to achieve to have an active link if I move cursor on the `li` tag, how can I do that?

Comment: Showcasing your issue with a fiddle would be helpful.

Comment: Does this work? This is not valid CSS...

Comment: Are you using less css? as xpy is mentioning this isn't valid.

Comment: Define 'active link'. I can't see any `:hover` definitions in the code that you posted?

Comment: Yes, it's Less. And also I forgot one bracket when I was making the code clearer.

Comment: Do you want an 'hover' effect over the LI element ?

Comment: Milche - yes, that's my goal. Sorry for complicated interpretation, I wasn't sure how to describe the desired behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the `<a>` `display: block;` and it should take up the available space of the list-item and thus be fully "clickable" ..

Comment: Ha! I love how this one gets accepted, even though it is identical to mine, and posted 6 mins later. I love StackOverflow sometimes...

Comment: LOL! I added a jsFiddle demo and removed the section that didn't accomplish what the OP needed (it wasn't clear in his original question what was being asked) - check the edit log... noob! http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15163216/revisions

Comment: Maybe you should make it a habit now, and avoid throwing around the term 'noob', it won't make you any friends here ;)

Comment: No problem. I just didn't really appreciate being called a noob by someone who clearly hadn't checked what he was talking about, or even looked at my rep :P

Answer (score 3):

Anchor elements are by default set to inline elements. You will need to explicitly set its display to block before adding width properties:

```
a {
    display: block;
}
```

See this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GmceK/).

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `li:hover` rule:

```
li:hover {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b6egd/

Comment: This obviously work, but it doesn't make the li clickable on the `A` link.